# iphone 4s is not connected to itunes

Tags: ios, windows

When I connect my iPhone 4S to my computer (Windows 7 32 bit), iTunes (11.2) does not detect the device. The phone displays the green battery meter indicating it's charging, I can sync the photos & videos, but when open itunes to copy songs, its not connected yet, i tried various USB cables,Itunes versions, but no hope. But i can connect it with from another Computer with 64 bit windows 7. i tried so many tricks via youtube too, i just purchased the phone last week.so kindly please help me. And 1 more thing, what is bonjour,it is used for?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling itunes on your pc?
As for bonjour:http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/45765/71490

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definately try this first:

- Go to the **Windows Menu**
- Right-mouse-click **Computer**
- Click **Manage**
- Go to **Device Manager**
- Open **Mobile Devices**
- **Uninstall** the driver for **Apple iPhone**

Connect your iPhone again and it should find the proper drivers again and iTunes should recognize your iPhone.

Re-installing iTunes is also an option.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps, testing to see if the issue is resolved after each section.

1. **Update iTunes**
2. **Check the USB cable**
3. **Verify that Apple Mobile Device Support is installed**
   (can be found in installed programs)
4. **Restart the Apple Mobile Device Service**
   Windows Vista or Windows 7
   Close iTunes and disconnect the iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch.
   Click the Windows Start button  Start button.
   In the Start Search field type Services.
   In the Programs section of the search results, Click "Services".
   Select Apple Mobile Device and click Stop the service.
5. **Verify that the Apple Mobile Device USB Driver is installed**
   1.Connect the device to the computer.
   2.Quit iTunes if it launches.
   **For Windows Vista and Windows 7:**
   3.Click the Start menu, right-click on Computer, and choose Properties.
   In the upper-left corner, click Device Manager. The Device Manager window should open.

   4.Click the plus (+) icon (or disclosure triangle () (for Windows 7 and Windows 8) next to "Universal Serial Bus controllers" to expand the selection.
   5.Locate the Apple Mobile Device USB Driver in this list. If this entry is displayed without any downward arrow, "!" or "?" symbols over it, then this driver is successfully installed.
   If the Apple Mobile Device USB Driver is not listed, reinstall it (instructions on apples site)
   If the Apple Mobile Device USB Driver entry is listed, but has an exclamation mark or question mark over it, continue to the next steps to reinstall the Apple Mobile Device driver.
6. **Check for third-party software conflicts**
   Uninstall any cellular device connectivity software from vendors such as Samsung, Nokia, Bora, Novatel, Sony, Android, LG, Sierra, Huawei, Pantech, or Motorola and see if the problem persists.
7. **Reinstall Itunes**

For a way more detailed explanation check here:http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1538